# Matlab differential equation verification

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

Consider $y^{\prime \prime} + y = 0$ and its solution candidate $\cos(t)$. Using MATLAB I would like to substitute the candidate into the differential equation and get verification that it is indeed a solution. How can I do this? I already know that the candidate is a solution, however, when I learn the procedure I will apply it to the other differential equations and solution candidates.

Comment: Jan Eerland has a nice answer, but it is not what I want.  I would like to verify a solution by MATLAB or some online software. If I verify the given solution then I think I can apply it to the other problems.  For instance, does  y'''(t)+y'(t)=sec(t) have the solution   y  =  c1 + c2 cos t + c3 sin t + ln|sec t + tan t|  -t cos t + (sin t) ln|cos t| ?  It is messy by hand, for this reason I want to verify it by MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to your problem can be computed by Laplace Transform
, and then you'll get:

$$y''(t)+y(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\text{d}^2y(t)}{\text{d}t^2}+y(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(t)=y(0)\sin(t)+y'(0)\cos(t)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(t)=c_2\sin(t)+c_1\cos(t)$$

---

Checking your $\cos(t)$ solution:

$$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\cos(t)+\cos(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\cos(t)+\cos(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(t)-\cos(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$0=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Matlab's Symbolic Math toolbox and [`isAlways`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isalways.html) in particular:

```
syms y(t)
f = diff(y,t,2)+y;
y_sol = cos(t);
isAlways(subs(f,y,y_sol) == 0)
```

returns `1` indicating that the candidate is a solution. Note that if your actual differential equations are much more complicated, it may not be feasible to prove that a candidate is a solution. You may also need to use [assumptions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions-1.html).